# Search based on multifilter using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to search the data based on name and description.For eg when I search by name the data displays fine and also when I search by only description the data displays fine. But when I want to display the data based on both name and description the data doesnt display properly only based on seperate fields it works fine.. But both together doesnt work fine. Here is the code

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="ss-name-filter">
                <select class="form-control" id="ss-description-filter">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="Not the metal.">Not the metal.</option>
                        
                    <option value="Women are from...">Women are from...</option>
                </select>
  <div class="row ss-box">
     
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4"
       data-description="Not the metal."
       data-name="Mercury">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <div class="caption">
            <h3>Mercury</h3>
            <p>Not the metal.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4"
       data-description="Women are from..."
       data-name="Mercury">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <div class="caption">
            <h3>Mercury</h3>
            <p>Women are from...</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4"
       data-description="Not the metal."
       data-name="Earth">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <div class="caption">
            <h3>Earth</h3>
            <p>Not the metal.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

<script>
       $(document).ready( function() {

var test = new simpleSort('.ss-box', 'div');

$('#ss-sort').on('click', function() {

    // toggle sort
    if(test.order === 'desc') {
        test.sort('data-name', 'asc');
    } else {
        test.sort('data-name', 'desc');
    }

});

// $('#ss-all').on('click', function() {
//     test.all();
// });

$('#ss-name-filter').on('propertychange change keyup paste input mouseup', function() {
    test.filter('data-name', $(this).val());
});

$('#ss-description-filter').on('propertychange change keyup paste input mouseup', function() {
    test.filter('data-description', $(this).val());
});  
$('#ss-name-filter, #ss-description-filter').on('propertychange change keyup paste input mouseup', function() {
    var nameFilterValue = $('#ss-name-filter').val().toLowerCase();
    var descriptionFilterValue = $('#ss-description-filter').val().toLowerCase();

    test.filter(function(item) {
        var itemName = $(item).attr('data-name').toLowerCase();
        var itemDescription = $(item).attr('data-description').toLowerCase();

        var nameMatch = itemName.includes(nameFilterValue);
        var descriptionMatch = itemDescription.includes(descriptionFilterValue);

        return nameMatch && descriptionMatch;
    });

});  
});    
       </script>

simplesort.js
   var simpleSort = function(parent, child, hiddenClass) {
this.stashBox = $(parent);
this.stashItems = this.stashBox.children(child);
this.order = ''; // used for external toggle check
this.hiddenClass = hiddenClass;

this.sort = function(dataAttribute, order) {

    order = (order === 'asc' || order === 'desc' ? order : 'desc');

    this.order = order;

    this.stashItems.sort( function(a,b) {

        var an = a.getAttribute(dataAttribute);
        var bn = b.getAttribute(dataAttribute);

        if(order === 'desc') {

            if(an > bn) {
                return 1;
            }
            if(an < bn) {
                return -1;
            }
            return 0;

        } else if (order === 'asc') {

            if(an < bn) {
                return 1;
            }
            if(an > bn) {
                return -1;
            }
            return 0;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
$('#ss-name-filter, #ss-description-filter').on('propertychange change keyup paste input mouseup', function() {
    var nameFilterValue = $('#ss-name-filter').val().toLowerCase();
    var descriptionFilterValue = $('#ss-description-filter').val().toLowerCase();

    test.filter(function(item) {
        var itemName = $(item).attr('data-name').toLowerCase();
        var itemDescription = $(item).attr('data-description').toLowerCase();

        var nameMatch = itemName.includes(nameFilterValue);
        var descriptionMatch = itemDescription.includes(descriptionFilterValue);

        return nameMatch && descriptionMatch;
    });
});
```

Comment: I used the above code.. But it doesnt display. I have updated the code

Comment: Have you checked, whether the code is being triggered or not when you make a change in name or description?

Comment: There is no changes in it.. It doesnt display based on name and description matches

Comment: And when I display value from the dropdown the matching data appears.. But when i click the textbox the all the data appears..

Comment: *"propertychange change keyup paste input mouseup"* ?? Just use `"input"`

Comment: Used input also but no change in it